# How to copy multiple files from multiple folders (each in one folder) to another folder?

Tags: r, copy, move

I'm trying to move `.jpg` files (Windows) that are each in one separate folder (named `IMG_somethingsomething`) to another folder, so that I can easily visualize the photos. I tried using a code that I saw from a similar problem, but it's not working...

`my_dirs` lists the correct directories where the files are, and files lists the `.jpg`, with `character(0)` under each name. Not sure that's what should happen? The new folder is created correctly, but nothing is copied.

```
my_dirs <- list.files("almond blossom", pattern = "IMG*", recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)

my_dirs

files <- sapply(my_dirs, list.files, full.names = TRUE)

files

# Your output directory to copy files to
new_dir <- "all.files"

# Make sure the directory exists
dir.create(new_dir, recursive = TRUE)


# Copy the files
for(file in files) {
 file.copy(file, new_dir, copy.mode = TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some points in your loop. You have to write from `1:length(files)`:

```
for(file in 1:length(files)) {
    file.copy(files[file], new_dir, copy.mode = TRUE)
}
```

If you already know that you pattern is a jpeg files I would change pattern for `.jpg` inside your firs line.

Besides you I would jump the line 3 of your code.

Then I would do something like that:

```
my_dirs <- list.files("almond blossom", pattern = ".jpg", recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)

new_dir <- "all.files"

dir.create(new_dir, recursive = TRUE)

for(file in 1:length(my_dirs)) {
    file.copy(my_dirs[i], new_dir, copy.mode = TRUE)
}
```

Hope this works!